# Cannot place WPF control from third party library on Grid

Tags: wpf, controls, graph-visualization

I'm using side library to add their UI control on the Window's Grid:

```
xmlns:graph="clr-namespace:Graphviz4Net.WPF"
```

this line throws an Exception in designer: The name [...] does not exist in the namespace

```
<graph:GraphLayout />
```

But I can be sure that this control exists in defined namespace and inherited from `Control` class

[image]

What is wrong in my XAML syntaxis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the name of the assembly there this control is (I suppose it is Graphviz4Net.WPF):
xmlns:graph="clr-namespace:Graphviz4Net.WPF;assembly=Graphviz4Net.WPF"